# Distorted Cabin & Oily Sheen: What is going on in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context, metaphors

I have been reading a book, and I have a question about the following excerpt:

> "We're here," The Tortoise in the Lake said, cutting across Dong Huong's gloomy thoughts.
>
> "I can see nothing."
>
> There came a low rumble, **which distorted the cabin** around her, and **cast an oily sheen on the walls**. "Watch."
>
> Outside, everything was dark. There was only the shadow of *The Two Sisters in Exile*, the dead ship that they'd been pulling since Longevity Station.
>
> – *The Two Sisters in Exile,* a fantasy novel by Aliette de Bodard

Are these changes happening in the “real” life of the novel?, or are they an illusion that exists merely in the mind of the narrator? If they are only an illusion, why does the author not say so? Has the author omitted something, or are these changes are really happening as the author says?

Comment: I believe the oily sheen is a reference to the lighting on the walls; I don't think there is really any petroleum-based substance involved. I imagine the walls of the cabin to be lit something like the outer walls in [this picture](http://www.opacity.us/images/db/103/196/0000006965.jpg).

Comment: I interpreted it as a figurative description of the visual effect caused by a large-amplitude low-frequency vibration.

Comment: I think @snailboat's got it. The rumble is the sound that accompanies the vibration (the ship is shaking) and because it's shaking, everything seems a bit blurry (which is figuratively described as a *distortion* and as giving the walls an *oily sheen*).

Comment: @WendiKidd - You may be right; I know nothing about this book. I don't know if it's a work of fiction or non-fiction, I can't tell if there is light cast by lightning (which would explain the low rumble), or if the sun is setting, or if the ship is up north where they can see the aurora borealis, or if there's something supernatural going on.

Comment: @J.R. Haha, fair point! The question was well-asked, but without reading the book we can't be completely sure. I wonder if this question is more literary-interpretation than English learning, but in an attempt to escape that I tried to go with the literal interpretation: if the only factor in the equation is that there's a "low rumble" (vibration implied) this is probably what it means. (That is, explaining the *rumble* rather than the surrounding context.) But still; not sure if that's quite possible here. Hence why I haven't answered :)

Comment: I think this is Off Topic, in that even native speakers can only give *opinions* about what exactly an "oily sheen" means in this context. Personally, I've never seen what a wall looks like in an earthquake. I imagine it looks a bit like jelly (U.S. jello) - but as I said, that's just one subjective opinion.

Comment: @J.R. this is a scientific-fiction novel, it tells us these ships are flying in the space; I think there are almost no stars around them(i.e. almost no light , very dark).

Comment: @Fumble Actually Im not sure what "oily sheen" means too, so Im not sure  what the whole sentence means . it's not a jelly.

Comment: Actually Im not sure what "oily sheen" means too, so Im not sure  what the whole sentence means too. so this question is about English learning and literary-interpretation too.thank you! @WendiKidd

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have a thing about perfectionism more or less, so I just try hard to understand what it means---for Im not so sure what the "oily sheen" means  , then not sure what the whole sentence means.

Comment: *Cabin* has a slightly different meaning in this context. The cabin almost certainly doesn't look like the one pictured.  Instead, *cabin* probably means "the enclosed compartment of an aircraft or spacecraft where passengers are carried" (definition from WordNet).

Comment: This question has been cross-posted at [elu.se] - see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/124135/43980 - but has been put 'On Hold' there. [Please do not post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: @TrevorD If the question was closed on ELU, it's allowed to be re-asked here. If the question is *open* on ELU, however, that's not allowed. :)

Comment: @WendiKidd Thanks. It was *posted* on ELU *subsequent* to being posted here, and subsequently closed because it had already been asked here. So clearly it fell in the 'not allowed' category. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I have substantially restructured this question from the original to make it more comprehensible. To view the original, click [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/9494/1)

Comment: @TrevorD It's also been posted to [Sci-fi & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/40364/1027).  And this is at least his third time reposting the same question on multiple SE sites.  There are 2 deleted questions on SFF that show the same behavior.

Comment: @Keen yes, it's about the same text, but different question, don't you see that?

Answer (score 6):

These are called "metaphors". A metaphor is when you say "A is B" when in reality A is not B, but only like it in some way. Like, "When Al insulted Bob, Bob became a raging lion." In real life Bob did not magically turn into a lion, but he acted like a wild animal.

People use metaphors because they make writing more lively and engaging. You could write, "Bob was mad and yelled at everybody." But that's fairly dull. It's much more interesting to write, "Bob was a raging lion, roaring wildly and tearing at everyone in sight." You could say, "She is pretty". But how much more picturesque to say, "She is a graceful swan gliding across the room."

Sometimes there's possible confusion whether the writer is being literal or using a metaphor. I suppose if in a fantasy novel you said "Bob became a raging lion" we might think that he literally was turned into an animal by some magical spell. Less dramatically, if you described a room as having "an oily sheen on the floor", in some cases a reader might legitimately wonder if you mean that as a metaphor describing the light and texture, or if someone literally spilled oil on the floor. But in real life it's rare for there to be any reasonable confusion. If there is, then don't use a metaphor.

Answer (score 2):

I find the paragraph rather odd. @Jay raised an interesting point about fantasy novels. I looked up the author and, indeed, she writes fantasy.

The author may be going for oddness deliberately - this is more common in fantasy than in some other forms of writing; it is highly unusual for a metaphor about sound (a rumble) to involve the visual (distorted and cast a sheen); context may provide clues. Is this a book full of magic of this sort? Might a wizard or some such be causing the rumble (as well as the distortion and sheen)?

Comment: This is a sci-fiction, so there are fantasy things here. and in physics, there's possible a sound like a low rumble to cause a object like a cabin to distort, and since the walls of the cabin is distorted, then the light on the walls could be changed, like an oily sheen.

Comment: so the problem of my confusion is that im not so sure I understand it very right, and seems the people here understand the English but not physics, and the problem of my confusion is I can't cross post my questions.can't change, SE? @Jay , i have confusion about the text, so you mean these changes are happening in real life?

Comment: A somewhat over-the-top example: sonic boom. A sonic boom is an explosion of sound energy. Such energy can also be called a shock wave and shock waves (which are not always sound, and can often be pure energy) can definitely affect physical objects. Now, as for whether a 'low rumble' could distort oil sheen, my rather basic science knowledge would think that's somewhat difficult, though if the environment was completely still, then even a small disturbance of energy (the sound from the rumble) might cause an effect. @Jay

Comment: I haven't read the book so all I know is the excerpt you gave above. But based on that, my first thought would be that the writer's meaning is that the rumble was so physically disturbing that it distorted her perception of the room about her, not that the room was actually physically distorted. But it's hard to say without more context.

Comment: i think about it again... if a sound like a sonic bomb can change the walls, and effect the people too, so i think just an inner sound to effect the walls . @Jay

Comment: forgive my bad english, i mean : if a sound like a sonic bomb can change the walls, sure it can effect the people too. so i think just an inner sound to effect the walls . @Jay

Comment: From the brief excerpt above, I suspect that what the writer meant was that the rumble was so disturbing, physically or mentally, that she could no longer see clearly. Is it possible for sound waves to distort the physical structure of a building? Sure. I doubt that that is the meaning here, but without more context and a feel for the writer's style, I can't say. But don't try too hard to find a literal meaning when the most obvious reading is mental or metaphorical. Like, if I read, "Bob was green with envy", yes, there are medical conditions that can make a person's skin ...

Comment: ... turn green, but the more likely reading is that this is symbolic language and not literal. If the next paragraph talks about the building collapsing from the stress, okay, the writer probably meant a literal physical distortion. But more likely this is talking about Dong's perceptions and emotional state.

Comment: the author said this is not an illusion, but it's a local modification of space time that happens because of the mindships. again, have no idea what does this mean... could you tell me why? @Jay

Comment: If it's a distortion caused by the "mindships", well, to the best of my knowledge there is no such thing in real life as a "mindship", that's something the author has invented. So it means whatever the author says it means. It may or may not have any relationship to real physics. As this is a fantasy novel, that would be doubly true.